# How to add a linker flag in Cython?

Tags: c++, json, compilation, cython

While compiling a Cython `setup.py` file, I provided additional flags via the `extra_compile_args` argument of `extensions`, i.e.,

```
extensions = [
    Extension(
        'tests', 
        sources=['test.pyx'], 
        extra_compile_args=["-ljsoncpp", "-std=c++11", "-I."]
    )
]
```

What I have noticed was that the flag, for example `-ljsoncpp` was only used at the first stage of creating the object `.o` file; it is missing in the second stage of creating a `.so` file. As this linker flag is required to produce a `.so` that can deal with JSON properly, I am wondering if it is possible to add this flag to the second stage of compiling. If possible, how should I do this?